# Proof of the convexity of the unit circle using the distance between two points

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, circles

There is an example for proof to convexity of a unit circle in Professor Arora's "Introduction to optimum design".

> Show the convexity of the set
>   $$
> S = \left\{\mathbf{x} \ \middle|\  x_1^2 + x_2^2 -1.0 \leq 0 \right\}
> $$

I know a proof to use triangular inequality to prove the convexity of the above set.

But, the book suggests the following:

> $$\mathbf{x} = \alpha \mathbf{x}^{(2)} + (1-\alpha)\mathbf{x}^{(1)} ; \quad 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1 \tag{4.71}$$
>   We can also use Eq. (4.71) to show convexity of $S$. To do this, take any two points $\mathbf{x}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}$ in the set $S$.  Use of Eq. (4.71) to calculate $\mathbf{x}$ and the condition that the distance between $\mathbf{x}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbf{x}^{(2)}$ is non-negative (that is, $\lVert \mathbf{x}^{(1)}- \mathbf{x}^{(2)} \rVert \geq 0$)  will show $\mathbf{x} \in  S$.

I am trying the manner suggested in the book rather than using  triangular inequality. But I can not find a solution.

How can $\lVert \mathbf{x}^{(1)}- \mathbf{x}^{(2)} \rVert \geq 0$ be applied to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ that belong to the set $S$. Then we must prove:
$$(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)^2+(ty_1+(1-t)y_2)^2\le 1.$$
We expand the brackets and regroup:
$$t^2(x_1^2+y_1^2)+2t(1-t)(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)+(1-t)^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)\le t^2+2t(1-t)+(1-t)^2=1,$$
because:
$$x_1^2+y_1^2\le 1; x_2^2+y_2^2\le 1;$$
$$x_1x_2+y_1y_2\le \frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}+\frac{y_1^2+y_2^2}{2}=\frac{(x_1^2+y_1^2)+(x_2^2+y_2^2)}{2}\le \frac{1+1}{2}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to avoid the triangle inequality in some way.

The function $\|x\| = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ is convex.

If $\|x\| \le 1$ and $\|y\| \le 1$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$ then
$\|\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y\| \le \alpha \|x\| + (1-\alpha) \|y\| \le 1$.